# golang int reference to string

Tags: string, go, data-conversion

Please help me understand this, maybe I'm doing something wrong.

```
func main() {
    x := 6
    y := &x
    fmt.Println("x: ", x, ", y:", *y, "string y:", string(*y))
}
```

returns:

```
x:  6 , y: 6 string y:
```

Why string(*y) does not return 6 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [specification says](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions_to_and_from_a_string_type):

> Converting a signed or unsigned integer value to a string type yields a string containing the UTF-8 representation of the integer.

The expression `string(*y)` evaluates to `"\x06"`. This is a string with the one byte 6.

Use [strconv.Itoa](https://godoc.org/strconv#Itoa) to convert an integer to a string:  `strconv.Itoa(*y) == "6"`.

Note that `*y` evaluates to 6. The pointer dereference used in the application has no impact on how the string type conversion executes.

Comment: Thank you, I misunderstood the usage of string cast. I will read the specification more carefully

Answer (score 1):

The `string` method converts ASCII indexes into characters, you need strconv's `Itoa`

https://play.golang.org/p/ouRqTIApWo